# How do I see previously sent friend requests on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I know how to see requests sent to me. But is there a way to see all the friend requests I've sent yet not approved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see it here: [Friend Requests Sent](https://www.facebook.com/friends/requests?outgoing=1).

<sub>([source](https://www.facebook.com/help/124960554250816))</sub>

[image]